# Назва для теки favorites, "избранное"

Tags: вибір-слова

Перекладаю командну і адміністративну панель сайту. Застрягла на назві теки "*избранное*". [Російсько-український словник А.Кримського](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on) та інші пропонує ряд

> И́збранный –  1) прил. ви́браний, ви́бо́рний, (отборный) добі́рний,
>   відбі́рний. [Вони́ задовольня́ли потре́бу всіє́ї ма́си наро́ду, а не
>   сами́х ті́льки небагатьо́х ви́браних (Грінч.). І тала́нт Шевче́нка, і
>   його́ життя́ – це надзвича́йна траге́дія ви́борної лю́дської нату́ри
>   (Єфр.)].
>
> • -ное общество, -ная публика – ви́борне, ви́бране  товари́ство,
>   ви́борна, ви́брана, добі́рна пу́бліка.
>   • -ные сочинения – ви́брані
>   писа́ння, (наилучшие) добі́рні писа́ння;

Традиційно для теки з такою назвою вживають слово "*вибране*". Але на сайті наявна ще і функція вибору оголошень, наприклад, для переміщення, поновлення, продовження і т.д. В такому випадку команда "Відкрити вибрані оголошення" може стосуватись тих, що в теці, чи тих, що позначені для певної дії. Чи є спосіб уникнути двозначності, змінивши назву теки на щось доречне, але зрозуміле пересічному користувачу?

Comment: І ще одне питання про переклад. Знову рекомендую не зациклюватися на дослівності. Спробуйте слово "Обране/Обрані" залежно від контексту можете доповнити уточнюючим словом. Також можна використати слово "Збережені", наприклад, збережені оголошення. які можна переглянути пізніше.

Comment: @Bohdanko, [намагайтеся уникати](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/197/) (напів-)відповідей у коментарях. Коментарі під запитанням призначені лише для покращення запитання. Усе інше рано чи пізно буде видалене.

Comment: По-моєму, варто додати до запитання слово «favorites» («favourites»). Бо в оригіналі, як я розумію, воно називається саме так. І наступний читач може шукати відповідь за словом «favorites» («favourites») — щоб воно гуглилося за обома словами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Bookmarks*:

- **за́кладки** ([KDE](//l10n.kde.org/team-infos.php?teamcode=uk), [Microsoft](//www.microsoft.com/en-us/language/Search?&searchTerm=bookmarks&langID=Ukrainian&Source=true&productid=All%20Products)).

*Favo(u)rites*:

- **улюблене**, *улюблені* ([KDE](//l10n.kde.org/team-infos.php?teamcode=uk), [Microsoft](//www.microsoft.com/en-us/language/Search?&searchTerm=favorites&langID=Ukrainian&Source=true&productid=All%20Products));
- **уподобання** ([Microsoft](//www.microsoft.com/en-us/language/Search?&searchTerm=favorites&langID=Ukrainian&Source=true&productid=All%20Products)).

*Saved*:

- **збережене** (Facebook).

Comment: Фейсбук має функцію збереження, яка по суті додає закладку на допис. В українському інтерфейсі вона називається "Збережене".

Comment: @Artemix, а десь можна подивитися словник Facebook (які слова як саме вони перекладають)?

Comment: Можу запропонувати тільки в налагодженнях виставити англійську і українську і порівняти. Англійською цей пункт меню називається Saved, але на іконці намальована книжкова закладка.

Comment: @Artemix, я десь у них бачив розділ сайту чи групу, присвячену перекладу (тобто де добровольці перекладають/перевіряють/виправляють інтерфейс Facebook).